# HSTS and Chrome

Tags: nginx, hsts

```
Error 102 (net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED): The server refused the connection.
```

This is what Chrome shows when you go to https://struct.tumblr.com/.
I then CNAME this to a subdomain like blog.mysite.com and i have HSTS on in my Nginx config like so:

```
add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=315360000; includeSubdomains ";
```

I use a wildcard ssl cert for a multi-tennant site, and blog is cnamed to tumblr.  So I think NGINX automagically redirects to https://blog.mysite.com and since that throws up Chrome 102 error, i can never see the blog through my cname in Chrome.

Can i tell nginx to somehow 'all subdomains but blog'?

Thanks